# Non-free-font (garamondx) is not being rendered anymore after upgrade to macOS 13

Tags: fonts, macos, kpathsea, garamondx

I have been creating PDFs with `garamondx` for a while without a problem on my Mac with M1 chip. After upgrading to macOS 13 (Ventura) garamondx as a non-free font cannot be rendered anymore. The error message goes:

On TeXstudio:

> "kpathsea: Running mktexpk --mfmode / --bdpi 600 --mag 1+120/600 --dpi 720 newG8-Reg-swq
> mktexpk: don't know how to create bitmap font for newG8-Reg-swq. mktexpk: perhaps newG8-Reg-swq is missing from the map file.
> kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.
> Process exited with error(s)"

On TeXShop:

> "!pdfTeX error: /Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex (file zgmb8r): Font zgmb8r at 1037"

Troubleshooting:

1. I have already updated my TeX Live to the 2023 version. Problem was with 2022 as well.
2. My `texmf-local` folder is properly installed and contains all font files and folders containing my garamondx font.
3. I am sure that `newG8-Reg-swq.tfm` is installed at `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/fonts/tfm/public/garamondx`
4. I installed garamondx by using getnonfreefonts.
5. All packages have been recently updated.

**Example**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{garamondx}
\begin{document}
  Test
\end{document}
```

Creates the error above and produces logfile below:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (TeX Live 2023) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2023.5.3)  3 MAY 2023 18:13
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**trst.tex
(./trst.tex
LaTeX2e <2022-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2023-04-20>
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2022/07/02 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2022/07/02 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count185
\c@section=\count186
\c@subsection=\count187
\c@subsubsection=\count188
\c@paragraph=\count189
\c@subparagraph=\count190
\c@figure=\count191
\c@table=\count192
\abovecaptionskip=\skip48
\belowcaptionskip=\skip49
\bibindent=\dimen140
)
(/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/tex/latex/garamondx/garamondx.sty
Package: garamondx 2017/03/11 v1.12

`garamondx' v1.12. 2017/03/11 GaramondNo8 with expert features (Michael Sharpe)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 2021/09/16 v1.2d Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2022/05/29 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks16
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2022/03/10 v1.4e Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty
Package: trig 2021/08/11 v1.11 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 107.

(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def
File: pdftex.def 2022/09/22 v1.2b Graphics/color driver for pdftex
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen141
\Gin@req@width=\dimen142
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
Package: fontenc 2021/04/29 v2.0v Standard LaTeX package

(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ly1/ly1enc.def
File: ly1enc.def 2022/06/11 v0.8 TeX 'n ANSI encoding (DPC/KB)
Now handling font encoding LY1 ...
... processing UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding LY1

(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ly1enc.dfu
File: ly1enc.dfu 2022/06/07 v1.3c UTF-8 support
   defining Unicode char U+00A0 (decimal 160)
   defining Unicode char U+00A1 (decimal 161)
   defining Unicode char U+00A2 (decimal 162)
   defining Unicode char U+00A3 (decimal 163)
   defining Unicode char U+00A4 (decimal 164)
   defining Unicode char U+00A5 (decimal 165)
   defining Unicode char U+00A6 (decimal 166)
   defining Unicode char U+00A7 (decimal 167)
   defining Unicode char U+00AA (decimal 170)
   defining Unicode char U+00AB (decimal 171)
   defining Unicode char U+00AD (decimal 173)
   defining Unicode char U+00AE (decimal 174)
   defining Unicode char U+00B0 (decimal 176)
   defining Unicode char U+00B5 (decimal 181)
   defining Unicode char U+00B6 (decimal 182)
   defining Unicode char U+00B7 (decimal 183)
   defining Unicode char U+00BA (decimal 186)
   defining Unicode char U+00BB (decimal 187)
   defining Unicode char U+00BC (decimal 188)
   defining Unicode char U+00BD (decimal 189)
   defining Unicode char U+00BE (decimal 190)
   defining Unicode char U+00BF (decimal 191)
   defining Unicode char U+00C0 (decimal 192)
   defining Unicode char U+00C1 (decimal 193)
   defining Unicode char U+00C2 (decimal 194)
   defining Unicode char U+00C3 (decimal 195)
   defining Unicode char U+00C4 (decimal 196)
   defining Unicode char U+00C5 (decimal 197)
   defining Unicode char U+00C6 (decimal 198)
   defining Unicode char U+00C7 (decimal 199)
   defining Unicode char U+00C8 (decimal 200)
   defining Unicode char U+00C9 (decimal 201)
   defining Unicode char U+00CA (decimal 202)
   defining Unicode char U+00CB (decimal 203)
   defining Unicode char U+00CC (decimal 204)
   defining Unicode char U+00CD (decimal 205)
   defining Unicode char U+00CE (decimal 206)
   defining Unicode char U+00CF (decimal 207)
   defining Unicode char U+00D0 (decimal 208)
   defining Unicode char U+00D1 (decimal 209)
   defining Unicode char U+00D2 (decimal 210)
   defining Unicode char U+00D3 (decimal 211)
   defining Unicode char U+00D4 (decimal 212)
   defining Unicode char U+00D5 (decimal 213)
   defining Unicode char U+00D6 (decimal 214)
   defining Unicode char U+00D8 (decimal 216)
   defining Unicode char U+00D9 (decimal 217)
   defining Unicode char U+00DA (decimal 218)
   defining Unicode char U+00DB (decimal 219)
   defining Unicode char U+00DC (decimal 220)
   defining Unicode char U+00DD (decimal 221)
   defining Unicode char U+00DE (decimal 222)
   defining Unicode char U+00DF (decimal 223)
   defining Unicode char U+00E0 (decimal 224)
   defining Unicode char U+00E1 (decimal 225)
   defining Unicode char U+00E2 (decimal 226)
   defining Unicode char U+00E3 (decimal 227)
   defining Unicode char U+00E4 (decimal 228)
   defining Unicode char U+00E5 (decimal 229)
   defining Unicode char U+00E6 (decimal 230)
   defining Unicode char U+00E7 (decimal 231)
   defining Unicode char U+00E8 (decimal 232)
   defining Unicode char U+00E9 (decimal 233)
   defining Unicode char U+00EA (decimal 234)
   defining Unicode char U+00EB (decimal 235)
   defining Unicode char U+00EC (decimal 236)
   defining Unicode char U+00ED (decimal 237)
   defining Unicode char U+00EE (decimal 238)
   defining Unicode char U+00EF (decimal 239)
   defining Unicode char U+00F0 (decimal 240)
   defining Unicode char U+00F1 (decimal 241)
   defining Unicode char U+00F2 (decimal 242)
   defining Unicode char U+00F3 (decimal 243)
   defining Unicode char U+00F4 (decimal 244)
   defining Unicode char U+00F5 (decimal 245)
   defining Unicode char U+00F6 (decimal 246)
   defining Unicode char U+00F8 (decimal 248)
   defining Unicode char U+00F9 (decimal 249)
   defining Unicode char U+00FA (decimal 250)
   defining Unicode char U+00FB (decimal 251)
   defining Unicode char U+00FC (decimal 252)
   defining Unicode char U+00FD (decimal 253)
   defining Unicode char U+00FE (decimal 254)
   defining Unicode char U+00FF (decimal 255)
   defining Unicode char U+0131 (decimal 305)
   defining Unicode char U+0141 (decimal 321)
   defining Unicode char U+0142 (decimal 322)
   defining Unicode char U+0152 (decimal 338)
   defining Unicode char U+0153 (decimal 339)
   defining Unicode char U+0160 (decimal 352)
   defining Unicode char U+0161 (decimal 353)
   defining Unicode char U+0174 (decimal 372)
   defining Unicode char U+0175 (decimal 373)
   defining Unicode char U+0176 (decimal 374)
   defining Unicode char U+0177 (decimal 375)
   defining Unicode char U+0178 (decimal 376)
   defining Unicode char U+017D (decimal 381)
   defining Unicode char U+017E (decimal 382)
   defining Unicode char U+0192 (decimal 402)
   defining Unicode char U+0218 (decimal 536)
   defining Unicode char U+0219 (decimal 537)
   defining Unicode char U+021A (decimal 538)
   defining Unicode char U+021B (decimal 539)
   defining Unicode char U+0237 (decimal 567)
   defining Unicode char U+02C6 (decimal 710)
   defining Unicode char U+02DC (decimal 732)
   defining Unicode char U+2013 (decimal 8211)
   defining Unicode char U+2014 (decimal 8212)
   defining Unicode char U+201C (decimal 8220)
   defining Unicode char U+201D (decimal 8221)
   defining Unicode char U+2020 (decimal 8224)
   defining Unicode char U+2021 (decimal 8225)
   defining Unicode char U+2022 (decimal 8226)
   defining Unicode char U+2026 (decimal 8230)
   defining Unicode char U+2030 (decimal 8240)
   defining Unicode char U+2039 (decimal 8249)
   defining Unicode char U+203A (decimal 8250)
   defining Unicode char U+2122 (decimal 8482)
   defining Unicode char U+FB00 (decimal 64256)
   defining Unicode char U+FB01 (decimal 64257)
   defining Unicode char U+FB02 (decimal 64258)
   defining Unicode char U+FB03 (decimal 64259)
   defining Unicode char U+FB04 (decimal 64260)
   defining Unicode char U+FB05 (decimal 64261)
   defining Unicode char U+FB06 (decimal 64262)
)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontaxes/fontaxes.sty
Package: fontaxes 2020/07/21 v1.0e Font selection axes
LaTeX Info: Redefining \upshape on input line 29.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \itshape on input line 31.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \slshape on input line 33.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \swshape on input line 35.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \scshape on input line 37.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \sscshape on input line 39.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ulcshape on input line 41.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \textsw on input line 47.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \textssc on input line 48.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \textulc on input line 49.
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/textcomp.sty
Package: textcomp 2020/02/02 v2.0n Standard LaTeX package
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty
Package: etoolbox 2020/10/05 v2.5k e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
\etb@tempcnta=\count193
))
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for T1+zgmx on input line 5
.

(/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/tex/latex/garamondx/t1zgmx.fd
File: t1zgmx.fd 2012/10/29 Fontinst v1.933 font definitions for T1/zgmx.
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def
File: l3backend-pdftex.def 2023-04-19 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)
\l__color_backend_stack_int=\count194
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box51
)
(build/trst.aux)
\openout1 = `trst.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for LY1/ptm/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for LY1+ptm on input line 5
.
 (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ly1/ly1ptm.fd
File: ly1ptm.fd 2001/02/01 font definitions for LY1/ptm using Berry names.
)
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.

(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count195
\scratchdimen=\dimen143
\scratchbox=\box52
\nofMPsegments=\count196
\nofMParguments=\count197
\everyMPshowfont=\toks17
\MPscratchCnt=\count198
\MPscratchDim=\dimen144
\MPnumerator=\count199
\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count266
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks18
) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg/epstopdf-base.sty
Package: epstopdf-base 2020-01-24 v2.11 Base part for package epstopdf
Package epstopdf-base Info: Redefining graphics rule for `.eps' on input line 4
85.

(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg
File: epstopdf-sys.cfg 2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Liv
e
))
\c@mv@tabular=\count267
\c@mv@boldtabular=\count268

[1

{/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
(build/trst.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 2370 strings out of 476001
 37064 string characters out of 5789200
 1850074 words of memory out of 5000000
 22860 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 518673 words of font info for 36 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 72i,5n,76p,206b,113s stack positions out of 10000i,1000n,20000p,200000b,200000s

!pdfTeX error: /Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex (file zgmr8r): Font zgmr8r at 600 n
ot found
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Comment: you seem to not have activated the map-file correctly.

Comment: how do I activate the map-file?

Comment: put `\pdfmapfile{=zgm.map}` in a document and test. If that works the map is the problem. You then can (probably) enable the map generally by calling `updmap-sys -enable Map=zgm.map`

Comment: I reactivated it the map-file. The funny thing is that at first it didn't find newG8. This seems to belong to my garamond font. After updmap-sys --syncwithtrees  the updmap.cfg and updmap-sys -enable Map=zgm.map the file is activated and with no error. But my garamondx errors remain stil the same.

Comment: make a small complete example, and show it together with the log-file.

Comment: Sure, I've been editing my querry above. There you can find the logfile.

Comment: well it works for me. Check if `usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map`  is actually updated if you run `updmap-sys`, and if it contains the content of the zgm.map. If not check which updmap.cfg it reads and check them.

Comment: It works for me, too. Now that I also ran updmap-sys. Something was messed up, but now it runs again. Thank you so much Ulrike!